# GeoDjango equivalent of ST_GeomFromGeoJson?

Tags: django, python-3.x, spatial, geodjango

What is the equivalent of `ST_GeomFromGeojson()` in ***GeoDjango***?

I'm looking for it in GeoDjango's documentation but there's only `AsGeoJSON` as its output format. This can be done both using `annotate` and `serialize`.

But what if I want to have a GeoJson object that I need to turn back to Geom?

Use Case:

```
geom_test = Geom.objects.filter(poly__within = [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(d)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#creating-a-geometry)

> GEOSGeometry objects may be created in a few ways. The first is to simply instantiate the object on some spatial input – the following are examples of creating the same geometry from WKT, HEX, WKB, and GeoJSON:
>
> ```
> # Other stuff I cut out.
>
> pnt = GEOSGeometry('{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 5.000000, 23.000000 ] }') # GeoJSON
> ```

So essentially `GEOSGeometry(GeoJSONString)`